# React-Native-SVG: Masked elements pixelated in android emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

In my app I have this code:

```
    <Svg width={W} height={H} viewBox={viewBox} style={style} preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <Defs>
        <Mask id="mask" x={0} y={0} width={W} height={H} maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
          <Nested name="Path" animated d={path} stroke="white" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={10} strokeDasharray="5 60" strokeDashoffset={pathOffset}/>
        </Mask>
      </Defs>

      <G mask="url(#mask)">
        <Nested name="Path" d={path} stroke="orange" strokeLinejoin="round"/>
        {fields.map( f => <Nested key={f.id} {...f}/>)}
      </G>

    </Svg>
```

where `Nested` is a delegation to `Path`, `Circle` and other RN-SVG elements.

Now, if the `G@mask` is removed, the element in Android Emulator or on real device it looks like so:

[image]

With `G@mask` it is displayed with reduced precision / pixelated / blurred:

[image]

I prepared a snack -> https://snack.expo.dev/@injecteer/react-native-svg-mask and in web-mode the mask with the animation looks just fine (the bottom line):

[image]

How to display the masked elements in full precision? What am I missing?

Comment: does it look blurred in a real android device too? or only on an emulator? this could be caused by the emulator's rendering precision too. Can you test with an emulator with higher resolution?

Comment: it's blurred/pixelated both on emulator and real device with FullHD+